# How to prove this equation has no real answer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wanted to solve this equation , after trying several approaches , wondered if it has a real answer . I used Wolframalpha and it told me that it does not have any ! Can we ever prove that an equation does not have a real answer? how ?
$$ \sqrt{72 - x}  + \sqrt{x - \frac{72}{x}} = x $$
I tried to indicate the common domain , I expected it to be an empty set but it wasn't.

Comment: Reading the title, I thought this was some kind of variation on the Russell paradox.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen it might be!

Answer (score 3):

If you move the $x$ to the LHS, and if you proved that the LHS function is always greater than zero then you can conclude that there is no solution to this function for real numbers. In this case, I believe it has a solution and its $x=9$

Your new equation does not have a solution. While there is domain for which both of the functions overlap, there is no solution. This is best seen with a graph of the function.

Comment: Oh yes , what a mistake .

Comment: I edited the equation , sorry.

Comment: I think graph isn't a proof.

Comment: You can estimate the graph using calculus and from there you can see that it never intersects the x-axis. But, this process would take so much time. Using a GC program is easier...

Answer (score 1):

This equation has only one solution and it can check by drawing graph that y = x cut y = sqrt(72 - 72/x) +sqrt(x-72/x) at only one point .

Comment: $\sqrt{63}+1\ne 9$.

Comment: Oh You have edited the question .

Comment: is drawing the graph a strong proof ? isn't that intuitive?

Comment: @ amtr No, drawing graph is not easy all time here also it is difficult  to draw graph for L.H.S. function . It is better sometime to draw a graph if proof is not easy or not getting through proof or tired by proof .